# Rendering platform agnostic wrapper in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In a library I'm writing, there is a component which adds props to it's children then renders them. Because React only renders 1 element, the children have to be wrapped in something. Up until trying to port the library to React Native it was wrapping in a `div`. That doesn't work in React Native however.

Is there a platform agnostic wrapper that will automatically choose the correct one depending on platform? Or is there a way to write logic that will choose between `div` and `View` at runtime?

I don't want to write one for web and one for native with the only difference being `div` swapped for `View`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> View maps directly to the native view equivalent on whatever platform React is running on, whether that is a UIView, `<div>`, android.view, etc.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/view.html

Comment: Huh, Thanks. Seems weird that the platform agnostic solution is hidden in `react-native` and not just `react`.